# How to change color in circular progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am using circular progress bar on Android. I wish to change the color of this. I am using

```
"?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse"
```

style. So how to change the color of progress bar.

How to custom the style? Furthermore, what is the definition of the style?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

In the res/drawable folder, put this:

### `progress.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:pivotX="50%" 
      android:pivotY="50%" 
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape 
        android:shape="ring" 
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" 
        android:useLevel="false">

    <size 
        android:width="76dip" 
        android:height="76dip" />

    <gradient 
        android:type="sweep" 
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#447a29" 
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:angle="0"/>

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Set `startColor` and `endColor` as per your choice .

Now set that `progress.xml` in `ProgressBar`'s backgound .

### Like this

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
 />
```

Comment: its not working when I am using custom dialog as list view header. Is there need to another approach?

Comment: This creates a green ring shape, but the actual ProgressBar's spinner is still visible.

Comment: is there a way to make the spinning colors move in only one direction?

Comment: Instead of setting the background with "android:background", use "android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" instead, as highlighted by another answer

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly. @Chirag How can I make it to run some what faster ?

Comment: This did not work as expected. It displays a ring and then a regular spinning progress bar within. Muhamad's answer works better.

Comment: for me its not rotating

Comment: this is not the solution

Comment: Use  android:startColor="#447a29"  android:endColor="#227a29" values different so that it doesn't form a static circle.

Comment: As Abhishek said, there should be a big difference between whatever startColor and endColor you use, otherwise it will look static. For example, you can use android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary" and android:endColor="00ffffff" (solid white) and that will give you something from the theme.

Answer (score 188):

For API 21 and Higher. Simply set the indeterminateTint property. Like:

```
android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
```

To support pre-API 21 devices:

```
mProgressSpin.getIndeterminateDrawable()
                .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN );
```

Comment: with `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"` doesn't work

Comment: If I have an array of colors and I want to set color to a color array on the each progress bar

Comment: This worked fine for me, just to change the progressBar ring color :)

Comment: If I put this color it colors the spinning cutted ring but all of it, so it turns into a full ring so you dont see it moving

Answer (score 139):

1.First Create an xml file in drawable folder under resource

named "progress.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >

    <size
        android:height="76dip"
        android:width="76dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="color/pink"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

2.then make a progresss bar using the folloing snippet

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" />
```

Comment: Hi Muhamed, i am using custom progress wheel, i tried to change the color in progress wheel at runtime. i am tried for, Once I click on a button, the progress starts. I have set the color as green. After the progress reaches 100%, I want it to start again, only this time its color should be red. But, i could not able to do that.. if possible pls help me

Comment: Thanks. It work 100%. set progress.xml to android:indeterminateDrawable

Comment: When I tried this, it created a Thick border of circle. Any ideas how to reduce the border ?

Comment: Hi Tejas, Try to  change this line android:thicknessRatio="8" inside the progress.xml . You can try different values. Hope it will work.

Comment: It works but instead of two rings rotating against each other I get just a single ring. Any fix for this?

Comment: After removing `android:useLevel="false"` from `<shape>` tag started rotating in my pre-lollipop device. Thank you

Comment: How can we increase the rotation speed of this progress bar? Cos it is rotating very slowly.

Answer (score 68):

You can change color programmatically by using this code :

```
ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
v.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFcc0000,
                        android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

If you want to change ProgressDialog's progressbar color, u can use this :

```
mDilog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar)mDilog.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
            v.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFcc0000,
                    android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey how will i connect ProgressDialog's Progress Bar With Progress.xml ??

Comment: If I have an array of colors and I want to set color to a color array on the each progress bar

Answer (score 39):

To add to Dato's answer, i find SRC_ATOP to be a preferable filter to multiply as it better supports the alpha channel.

```
ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
v.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFcc0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: On 2.3.x this gives you a solid filled circle where MULTIPLY preserves transparency.

Comment: If I have an array of colors and I want to set color to a color array on the each progress bar

Comment: Use compat version: `progressBar.indeterminateDrawable.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(0xffffff, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP)`

Answer (score 35):

android:indeterminateTint="@color/progressbar"

Comment: just use above attribute in progress bar :indeterminateTint= your colour

Comment: Best answer and it would support for all versions also

Comment: This is all you need, not these crazy answers. Though others would benefit from the full code block.

Comment: indeterminateTint is available for API 21 or higher. If that works for you, terrific!

Answer (score 19):

styles.xml

```
<style name="CircularProgress" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
</style>

  <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d_40"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"/>
```

Comment: [i think this will help you](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel/blob/master/src/com/todddavies/components/progressbar/ProgressWheel.java)

Answer (score 16):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`CircularProgressIndicator`** with these attributes:

- `indicatorColor`
- `trackColor`

  ```
        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:trackColor="@color/..."
            app:indicatorSize="90dp"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/..."
            />
  ```

[image]

Comment: this one should be the accepted one as for now in 2021

Answer (score 15):

That's work for me.

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: Available from API level 21

Answer (score 11):

To customize circular ProgressBar we need to create a **indeterminateDrawable** to show custom progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#f96047"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#fb9c8d"
            android:startColor="#f72d0c"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

We need to include drawable in progressbar just as below:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/widget_progressbar"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/widget_progressbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: `rotate`tag is missing before `shape`. Without it, the progressbar will be static

Comment: @RenanBandeira you can improve the answer if its correct

Answer (score 11):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935670/2472350) out:

for me, these two lines had to be there for it to work and change the color:

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/yourColor"
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
```

PS: but its only available from android 21

Comment: The Only best simplest solution

Answer (score 10):

for me theme wasn't working with accentColor. But it did work with  colorControlActivated

```
    <style name="Progressbar.White" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>

  <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d_40"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:theme="@style/Progressbar.White"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<style name="progressColor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/progressColor"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Add to your activity theme, item **colorControlActivated**, for example:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            ...
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/rocket_black</item>
            ...
    </style>
```

Apply this style to your Activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".packege.YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

To supplement [Muhamed Riyas M's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17785769/3681880) top voted answer:

Faster rotation

```
android:toDegrees="1080"
```

Thinner ring

```
android:thicknessRatio="16"
```

Light white

```
android:endColor="#80ffffff"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using a style and set colorControlActivated too desired ProgressBar color.

```
<style name="progressColor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/COLOR</item>
</style>
```

Then set the theme of the ProgressBar to new style.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/progressColor"
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a style for changing the color of progress like below

```
 <style name="AppTheme.anyName">
        <item name="colorAccent">YOUR_COLOR</item>
    </style>
```

and use it in the ProgressBar like below

```
<ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_30"
        />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom dialog pretty easily, reusing the xml from other answers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <size
        android:height="76dip"
        android:width="76dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/oceanBlue"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />

</shape>
```

Just do this:

```
public static class ModifiedProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    public ModifiedProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        setIndeterminateDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_progress));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For all those wondering how to increase the speed of custom progress

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="1080"><!--HERE YOU COULD INCREASE SPEED BY SETTING TODEGRESS(1080 is 3 loops instead of 1 in same amt of time)-->
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">
    <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#447a29" 
        android:endColor="#447a29"
        android:angle="0"
         />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_custom_rotate"`

Use Below Code for Custom Circular Ring Progress Bar

Copy Below code and create "progress_custom_rotate.xml" in Drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1080">

    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="48dip" android:height="48dip" />

        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
            android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#ffffd300" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes color value from your Res/Values/Colors.xml -> colorAccent
if you change it, your progressBar color changes aswell.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="progressColor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/progressColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

---

Answer (score -1):

You can change your progressbar colour using the code below:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
    getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: If I have an array of color then ?