# How to change default color of progress bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I am using a circular `ProgressBar` in my Activty.My Problem is this it is not visible properly on my page because my page's BG color is same as ProgressBar .So how can I **change the color of ProgressBar** to make it properly Visible?
Please Help

Comment: please try solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Comment: I got the solution from [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2638877/1318946] May this link is useful to you

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Please make one xml file name progress.xml and put it in res/xml folder and write the below code in that xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#447a29" 
            android:endColor="#447a29"
            android:angle="0"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

after creating this xml file set your progressbars background as this xml ..

### Like

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background = "@xml/progress">
```

Comment: Thank You Chirag It was Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I think it should in drawable instead of xml

Comment: nice working fine absolutely it was absolutely what i wanted.

Answer (score 46):

The easiest way is to use 
android:indeterminateTint attribute:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/black"
        ........... />
```

Comment: This is supported from api 21 and up.

Comment: I think this is the best answer!

Answer (score 41):

This is an old question, but using theme is not mentioned here. If your default theme is using `AppCompat`, your `ProgressBar`'s color will be `colorAccent` you have defined.

Changing `colorAccent` will also change your `ProgressBar`'s color, but these changes also reflects at multiple places. So, if you want a different color just for a specific `ProgressBar` you can do that by applying theme to that `ProgressBar` alone:

- Extend your default theme and override `colorAccent`

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme.WhiteAccent">
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item> <!-- Whatever color you want-->
  </style>
  ```
- And in `ProgressBar` add the `android:theme` attribute:

  ```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
  ```

So it will look something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent" />
```

So you are just changing a `colorAccent` for your particular `ProgressBar`.

**Note**: Using `style` will not work. You need to use `android:theme` only.
You can find more use of theme here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH

**Edit**

Here is the code for changing the color of ProgressBar by programatically.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_listProgressBar);
int colorCodeDark = Color.parseColor("#F44336");
progressBar.setIndeterminateTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(colorCodeDark));
```

Comment: Nice answer, you can even have both `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"` with `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"`

Comment: You made my day. using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"` make the trick of changing `ProgressBar` color

Comment: This can also be used throughout the app wherever you need a white accentColor. Bravo!

Answer (score 9):

### Go to the declaration of the progress bar in your .xml file :

---

And **paste** this line of code :

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
```

The example above allows you to **change the color** of your progress bar to **white**. **Now** it's up to you to **adapt** it to **the color you want**.

*Only for Android API >= 21*

Answer (score 7):

in xml u can apply color like this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/my_color"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

for me, these two lines had to be there for it to work and change the color:

```
android:indeterminateTint="@color/yourColor"
android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
```

PS: but its only available from android 21

Answer (score 2):

create progress drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

and set
**android:progressDrawable="@drawable/app_progressbar_back"**

like this

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/dialogProgressView"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/app_progressbar_back"
                android:progress="50"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the color of your progressbar programmatically in your activities oncreate or your fragments onViewCreated()

```
pBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Here the color applied is "0xFFFF0000" which is red. You can change it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it by java code.

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.product_status_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
```

Comment: what if `getProgressDrawable()` returns null?

Comment: this is working for me on pre-lollipop devices, it can be null  on only after KitKat devices. for after lollipop devices i have something like this. progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);
I have check for build os version and apply the respective code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation. For changing background of a  `Indeterminate ProgressBar`, you need a rotating ring because it rotates. In the answer of @Chirag, he has defined a rotating ring and applied it to the background of `ProgressBar`. If you have a `Horizontal ProgressBar` then you need a `rectangle`.

PS: I have not tried with other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using android 2.3.1 version. I create a xml file called progressbar and call it in the layout progress bar tag android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"

```
<item android:id="@+id/progress">
    <clip>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/textColor"
            android:centerColor="@color/textColor"
            android:endColor="@color/textColor"
            android:gradientRadius="20dp"
            >
        </gradient>
    </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chirag's answer is right, but not all.
I think the XML file should look like this:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/.."` definitely changes the color of the progress bar background. But in my case, the progress was determinate.

I was able to change the color of both progress and progress background using the below lines within the progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar                                 
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:progressTint="@color/progress_green"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using CircularProgressIndicator, you can try:

```
app:indicatorColor="@color/yourColor"
app:indicatorSize="4dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

you also can change only the attribute

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/yourxmlfile"
```

and keep this style

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this in your XML

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/yourxmlfile"

style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
```