# How to override ProgressBar in order to change the progress fill to a drawable with rounded corners and color

Tags: android

I have a specific color that I create programmatically.

I use that color in a GradientDrawable.

I need to override some part of the ProgressBar source code in order to make it use that GradientDrawable in there, when creating the progress fill color, but I dont know which part should I override and where to put my code

This is the progressbar source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ProgressBar.java

This is the drawable I want to use, but it doesnt extend accordingly to the progress made

```
public static GradientDrawable progressBarProgressDrawable(Context context, float[] radii) {
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setCornerRadii(radii);
    shape.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_button));

    float brightness = 0.9f;
    float[] hsb = new float[] { 43, 23, (33 * brightness) };
    int alpha = 77;
    int newColor = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, hsb);
    shape.setColor(newColor);

    return shape;
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding a ProgressBar just for color changing? You can do it in an a lot easier way. Take a look here http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

Comment: check [this](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6421272/1777090)

Comment: use Drawable.setColorFilter on your progress Drawable

Comment: @pskink what porterduff mode should I use in this case?

Comment: getProgressDrawable returns null :(

Comment: not possible,  it cannot return null, post your code

Comment: Drawable shape = sbGoalProfile.getProgressDrawable();
  Log.d("asd", String.valueOf(shape));
  shape.setColorFilter(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.green_button), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP );

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    setContentView(pb);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setCornerRadius(32);
    final Drawable cd = new ClipDrawable(gd, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    pb.setProgressDrawable(cd);

    OnTouchListener l = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int progress = (int) (event.getX() * pb.getMax() / pb.getWidth());
            pb.setProgress(progress);
            float[] hsv = {
                    event.getX() * 360 / pb.getWidth(), 1, 1
            };
            int color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch " + Integer.toHexString(color));
            cd.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            return true;
        }
    };
    pb.setOnTouchListener(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar has a method [setBackgroundColor(int color)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29).

If you want to override it, you can

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundColor (int color) {
    int c = 0x0000ff00; // Using green
    super.setBackgroundColor(c);
}
```

Or you could just call

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.setBackgroundColor(c);
```

Comment: I want to change the progress fill color, not the background color

Comment: Also, I want to set a custom drawable that has rounded corners

Comment: so see the default progress Drawable defined in xml resource file