# Changing the progress bar color

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am using a circular ProgressBar in my Activty.
My Problem is that its color isnt changing properly where only BG color is Changing.
So how can I change the color of ProgressBar without BG.
I tried this thread- [How to change default color of progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421178/how-to-change-default-color-of-progress-bar)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEpyM.jpg

Comment: post some code. where's the xml for the progress bar?

Comment: @Vucko I used code from this thread stackoverflow.com/questions/6421178/how-to-change-default-color-of-progress-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all in xml files 
After some search I got the answer :

you progress bar code :

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
   />
```

and the progress drawable is consisting of a rotating ring has a gradiant color of your choise like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"

        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#007700" 
            android:endColor="#115511"
            android:angle="0"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

just like this , please rate this answer :)

Comment: I need the color changing code which should be present in the @drawable/anyfile

Comment: by the way the drawable that represented here is a 9patch images consisting of one color as u wish, there is a 9patch creating tool with the sdk you can use it.

Comment: currently I use AIDE :P

Comment: also I am a noob... so its difficult for me to understand everything

Comment: so what exactly your question ? which part you didn't understood ?

Comment: check the screenshot... BG color I dont want, only PBar colour change

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dnE1I.jpg check the result, it has a dark green bg.. i dnt want that ,only pbar with blue color :)

Comment: I used indeterminateTint & indeterminateTintMode and now it Works! Still Thanks for ur Help :)

Comment: you can still change the colors, look at the gradient properties
android:startColor="#007700"  this is the color to start with and will end with
android:endColor="#115511"
so change the color to yor choise :)

Answer (score 1):

Better way (using AppCompat libs):

```
final int color = Color.WHITE; // Or any other one
final ProgressBar progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable(), color);
```