# Android-How can I change the spinner in ProgressDIalog?

Tags: android

Ok. i know this as asked so many times before, but mine is a bit different.

I have the `GifImageView` repo. installed using this dependency:

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
```

Now, I have a GIF progress spinner in my drawable. How can I change the spinner? It doesn't matter if I need to create a custom layout, please show me how.
My progressDialog:

```
public void showProgressBar(String msg) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Logging out", "Loading", true);
}


public void dismissProgressBar() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

So, without going technical, can I change the normal spinner to a GifImageVIew?

Comment: Hi, it's library made by Polish company DroidOnRoids, so the best way would be ask them how to do it on its site or Github

Comment: @piotrek1543 I doubt you understand. My question is "How can I make a custom progressBar?"

Comment: The repo just gives me the `GifImageView`. I only mentioned that so you don't tell me to use Android's `Movie` thing. My question is how do I change the progressDialog to a custom view?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035421/how-to-change-progressdialog-spinner-color-in-android

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-change-color-in-circular-progress-bar