# Samsung device with Android 5.0 changes progressbar color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile, samsung-touchwiz

Samsung devices with Android 5.0 ignore my color for the progressbar (set in styles.xml). The default blue color of samsung is used instead.

```
<style name="Progress">
     <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The  progressbar is in a toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
...
>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:theme="@style/Progress"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you initialising the progressbars? can you post code which shows the creation of the progress bars / any relevant styles / themes?

Comment: updated.. it is working on other 5.0 devices

Comment: can you share the style?

Comment: it's the one in the question. What I meant: It's working on other Android 5.0 devices but not with samsungs..

Comment: in my device it doesnt show anything at all

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, this topic will help: https://medium.com/the-wtf-files/the-misterious-case-of-the-skewed-progressbar-75da47ddd767.

You should add an attribute: `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"` to a `ProgressBar` and also add a drawable. It is useful for infinite ProgressBar. If it's determinate, I will research a problem and report here. Also see: [How to change color in circular progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-change-color-in-circular-progress-bar).

For those who don't see a ProgressBar at all, see https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar/issues/1. Maybe an "Animation scale" in Developer Options of your device is turned off.

See also: https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar.