# Circle Progress Bar color doesn't change (Android)

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Basically i have a circular progress bar and i have set a style to it, but the color does not change at all, its just green the whole time.

Code:

```
               <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/markAssistedProgressLayout"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    style="@style/progressBarWhite"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Style file:

```
    <style name="progressBarWhite" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/cherry_red_10_percent_opacity</item>
    </style>
```

The pic:

[image]

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: The issue could be that `android:visibility="gone"`.

Comment: No, im setting it to visible:true in my activity class

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337613/how-to-change-color-in-circular-progress-bar)?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a style, i directly set a indeterminateTint.

```
                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/markAssistedProgressLayout"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"/>
```